# query works without WHERE but with it, not - " LIMIT 0, 25' in line 2"

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the query I execute:

```
SELECT IDEgzemplarz, Tytul 
FROM egzemplarze 
WHERE DoWypozyczenia = 0
INNER JOIN ksiazki ON egzemplarze.KsiazkaID = ksiazki.IDKsiazki
```

This is the query that I get in error "window":

```
SELECT IDEgzemplarz, Tytul 
FROM egzemplarze 
WHERE DoWypozyczenia = 0
INNER JOIN ksiazki ON egzemplarze.KsiazkaID = ksiazki.IDKsiazki 
LIMIT 0, 25
```

This is error:

> 1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax obok 'INNER JOIN ksiazki ON egzemplarze.KsiazkaID = ksiazki.IDKsiazki LIMIT 0, 25' w linii 2

I'm curious why that query adds at the end "LIMIT 0, 25" when I didn't typed it. The best is that if I run this query without statement "WHERE DoWypozyczenia=0" query works...

Do you have any idea? Thank you for help ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Change your Query from:

```
SELECT IDEgzemplarz, Tytul FROM egzemplarze WHERE DoWypozyczenia=0
INNER JOIN ksiazki ON egzemplarze.KsiazkaID = ksiazki.IDKsiazki
```

To:

```
SELECT IDEgzemplarz, Tytul FROM egzemplarze 
INNER JOIN ksiazki ON egzemplarze.KsiazkaID = ksiazki.IDKsiazki
WHERE egzemplarze.DoWypozyczenia=0
```

Actually You have placed `WHERE` clause at wrong position.

Comment: Why is it like that? Could you explain with human language? :)

Comment: According to SQL syntax, `WHERE` clause must be placed at the end of your query.

Please visit http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx. They explain it with human language better :-D

Answer (score 0):

WHERE clause in SQL needs to be at the end

Answer (score 0):

SQL statements consist of a set of clauses.  Your query wants to use four of them:  `SELECT`, `FROM`, `WHERE`, and `LIMIT`.  Note that `JOIN` is an *operator* not a clause.  The order of the clauses is exactly the order above.  `WHERE` follows `FROM`.

I would recommend that you learn to use table aliases and qualify all column names.

Your query should look more like:

```
SELECT e.IDEgzemplarz, k.Tytul 
FROM egzemplarze e INNER JOIN
     ksiazki k
     ON e.KsiazkaID = k.IDKsiazki 
WHERE k.DoWypozyczenia = 0;
```

I am guessing which tables the columns come from, so the `e`s and `k`s may not be correct.  The queries that you write should be explicit about where the columns come from.

I do not know why `LIMIT 0, 25` was added to your query.  This limits the number of rows to 25 rows in the result set.  My guess is that you have some setting in the application you are using to query the database.